# Put default value in url

Tags: laravel, url, parameters

**Hi I am trying to put default id value in my route url in Laravel. How do I achieve it? Please Help me. Thank you.**

```
Route::get('manageattendance/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\ManageAttendanceController::class, 'index'])- 
>name('manageattendance');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `{id}` with `{id?}` and if you have id as parameter on the `index` function, set it to the default value like:

```
public function index($id = 1){
  // your code
}
```